# How do I use the scanner input on multiple arrays at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am making a program that displays certain values of planets that are stored in multiple arrays and i need the input of the scanner to determine which array values should be displayed.

```
package eindopdrachtse;

import java.util.* ;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class EindopdrachtSE {
public static void main (String[] args) {

    // Arraylist van de namen
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("0 = Mercurius");
    names.add("1 = Venus");
    names.add("2 = Mars");
    names.add("3 = Jupiter");
    names.add("4 = Saturnus");
    names.add("5 = Uranus");
    names.add("6 = Neptunus");
    for (String name : names)
    {
        System.out.println(name);

    }


    // Vul planeet nummer in
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Vul hier uw nummer in:");
    int nummer = in.nextInt();

    if (nummer==0){
        System.out.println("De valversnelling is:"+ valversnelling[nummer] );
    double[] valversnelling = new double[7];
    valversnelling[0]= 2.78;
    valversnelling[1]= 8.60;
    valversnelling[2]= 3.72;
    valversnelling[3]= 22.9;
    valversnelling[4]= 9.05;
    valversnelling[5]= 7.77;
    valversnelling[6]= 11.0;

    double[] massa = new double[7];
    massa[0]= 0.0553;
    massa[1]= 0.8149;
    massa[2]= 0.1074;
    massa[3]= 317.94;
    massa[4]= 95.181;
    massa[5]= 14.531;
    massa[6]= 17.135;

    int[] temperatuur = new int[7];
    temperatuur[0]= 167;
    temperatuur[1]= 464;
    temperatuur[2]= -63;
    temperatuur[3]= -121;
    temperatuur[4]= -130;
    temperatuur[5]= -205;
    temperatuur[6]= -220;    

    } 

    }

    // Informatie opvragen van planeet
    //planeten: 
    //  0 = Mercurius
    //  1 = Venus
    //  2 = Mars
    //  3 = Jupiter
    //  4 = Saturnus
    //  5 = Uranus
    //  6 = Neptunus 


      }
```

as of now I didnt add all the arrays, I just added "valversnelling". I just need to understand the principle.

thanks to the person who can help me!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Have you a question ?

Comment: You are already doing what you asked for. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I need the input of the scanner to function as the number to which array should be selected.

Comment: You mean you need a function for receiving inputs?

Comment: I need the right values to be displayed, if the number = 0 it should display valversnelling[0]= 2.78; but how do it do that

Comment: So the output of the program here should be: 
De valversnelling is 2.78

Comment: Yeah...nobody here understands dutch so we have no clue what you need and what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling array value before initialized it.

Do like this:

```
double[] valversnelling = new double[7];
valversnelling[0]= 2.78;
valversnelling[1]= 8.60;
valversnelling[2]= 3.72;
valversnelling[3]= 22.9;
valversnelling[4]= 9.05;
valversnelling[5]= 7.77;
valversnelling[6]= 11.0;

double[] massa = new double[7];
massa[0]= 0.0553;
massa[1]= 0.8149;
massa[2]= 0.1074;
massa[3]= 317.94;
massa[4]= 95.181;
massa[5]= 14.531;
massa[6]= 17.135;

int[] temperatuur = new int[7];
temperatuur[0]= 167;
temperatuur[1]= 464;
temperatuur[2]= -63;
temperatuur[3]= -121;
temperatuur[4]= -130;
temperatuur[5]= -205;
temperatuur[6]= -220;    

if (nummer==0) {
    System.out.println("De valversnelling is:"+ valversnelling[nummer] 
}
```

Comment: that was it, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

> I need the right values to be displayed, if the number = 0 it should display valversnelling[0]= 2.78; but how do it do that

Your code is already doing that, just remove the if statement. The array index will print the corresponding data and print it after your array is initialized:

```
//if (nummer==0){    //remove the if-statement
    System.out.println("De valversnelling is:"+ valversnelling[nummer] );
```

**Complete Code:**

You can initialize the array elements without assigning them one by one:

```
double[] valversnelling = {2.78, 8.60, 3.72, 22.9, 9.05, 7.77, 11.0};
double[] massa = {0.0553, 0.8149, 0.1074, 317.94, 95.181, 14.531, 17.135};
int[] temperatuur = {167, 464, -63, -121, -130, -205, -220};

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Vul hier uw nummer in:");
int nummer = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("De valversnelling is:"+ valversnelling[nummer] );
```